# Relationship does not display related fields Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, relationship

Using Laravel 5.4

I have 2 tables: origins and coffees.

The relations between them:

In Coffee model:

```
public function origin()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Origin');
}
```

In the Origin model:

```
 public function coffee()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\Coffee');
}
```

In my controller I have this method:

```
$origins = Origin::with(['coffee' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('active', 1);
            $query->orderBy('name', 'asc');
        }])->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
```

In my view:

```
@foreach($origins as $origin)
    {{ $origin->name }}
    <pre>{{ $origin->coffee->name }}</pre>
@endforeach
```

I get this error:

Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance.

If I code:

```
@foreach($origins as $origin)
        {{ $origin->name }}
        <pre>{{ $origin->coffee }}</pre>
    @endforeach
```

I get all the coffees that belong to the origin.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$origin->coffee` is a collection, not a single object. Your models also tell us that one `Origin` model **has many** `Coffee` models.

To list all `coffee`s in the current `origin`:

```
@foreach($origins as $origin)
    {{ $origin->name }}

    @foreach($origin->coffee as $coffee)
    <pre>{{ $coffee->name }}</pre>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Ah, funny, I thought I tried that option but I think I might have made some spelling mistakes or something because it also gave me an error. Anyway, copy and paste your solution and all is fine, thank you!